# Only last function create effect when calling same function at a time with different parameter in react useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, use-effect

I have created a component called "CommonStyleGenerator", to generate simple style object with keys like height, width and bgColor. I have created a text fields in component and whenever text change in any of text field I am calling `onStyleChange` with changed field key and it's value to  store changed value in parent component.

Here is the **CommonStyleGenerator.js** component code :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const CommonStyleGenerator = ({ style = {
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
  bgColor: "#ffffff"
}, onStyleChange }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    onStyleChange("height", "100%");
    onStyleChange("width", "100%");
    onStyleChange("bgColor", "#ffffff"); //Only this getting effect.
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput 
        value={style?.height}
        placeholder="height"
        onChangeText={(text) => onStyleChange("height", text)}
        style={styles.textField}
      />
      <TextInput 
        value={style?.width}
        placeholder="width"
        onChangeText={(text) => onStyleChange("width", text)}
        style={styles.textField}
      />
      <TextInput 
        value={style?.bgColor}
        placeholder="background color"
        onChangeText={(text) => onStyleChange("bgColor", text)}
        style={styles.textField}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textField: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginVertical: 10
  }
})

export default CommonStyleGenerator;
```

And here is the code of how I called the component in my **App.js** :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import CommonStyleGenerator from './components/CommonStyleGenerator';

const App = () => {
  const [commonStyle, setCommonStyle] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', padding: 20}}>
      <CommonStyleGenerator 
        style={commonStyle}
        onStyleChange={(key, value) => setCommonStyle({
          ...commonStyle,
          [key]: value
        })}
      />
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(commonStyle, null, 2)}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Now, what I want is that on load **CommonStyleGenerator** component, generate default style if user don't change any textfield. So I called `onStyleChange` function on useEffect for each key. But for only last key(bgColor) function is called.

Is anyone know how I can solve this issue ?

[snack.expo.io link](https://snack.expo.io/@kishan_bharda/9aadd7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `commonStyle` in state when the three initial `onStyleChange`s are called is null. Each time it's called, the new state is set with an object with a single key. The synchronous call of an `onStyleChange` after a previous `onStyleChange` hasn't updated the `commonStyle` variable outside yet.

Your current code is like doing:

```
onStyleChange({ height: '100%' });
onStyleChange({ width: '100%' });
onStyleChange({ bgColor: '#ffffff' });
```

so only the last object passed appears to be in state on the next render.

Use a callback instead, when setting:

```
    onStyleChange={(key, value) => setCommonStyle(commonStyle => ({
      ...commonStyle,
      [key]: value
    }))}
```

Comment: Heyy thanks it worked. It worked for state value. I means If I set value on state. I have same another component like this, but when I calling that component in parent component, I save that values using formik `setFieldValue()` function. In that It not working. Can you please tell me how to solve for that ?

Comment: How isn't it working in Formik, exactly? I've never used it before but I'm not immediately seeing any problem with [using it](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) - as long as you pass different fields.

Comment: Can you please check this snack, basically `setFieldValue` set value to formik field. And I used that to set value but it only set last called function value.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to use call back in that ?

Comment: Oh, all the fields being set use the same key? That's the problem. If you can't use different keys, then it doesn't look possible https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2783 I think you might have to use state (like in the answer), then use `useLayoutEffect` to pass the state changes to `setFieldValue` all at once on next render.

Comment: I don't want to use state, because my other field are in formik and have to change too many code. So I'll try if anything possible with simple `setFieldValue`. Btw thanks very much to help.

Comment: Hey I have done something like https://snack.expo.io/@kishan_bharda/9aadd7 . Instead of changing simple key, now I am changing whole object. I want to know your opinion Do you think there will be any side effect ?

Comment: Sure, that looks reasonable, if your code layout allows you to have just a single `useEffect` like that, go for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done by passing whole object and `setFieldValue`.